# time based position determining software and placing an object at that position

Tags: animation

**What am I doing** : I want to animate a ball moving in a certain path

For example : a ball dropped on the floor vertically

**Constraints** : I should be able to determine the position of the ball(a circle) when I provide a certain set of equations (which are variables with respect to time). and a particular time T.

After determining the position then I need to place the ball(or circle) at that point.

Then I would be able to save this as an image and then make a sequence of such images for regular time intervals and then make an animation out of it.

**What am I looking for** : I am looking for a software which can do this job

You can even tell me two different softwares also to do this job.

1. One for determining the position and
2. for placing my object at that particular position

Any type of help would be appreciated

Thankyou for your valuable time